# Accessing member from casted generic pointer in derived class causes Access Violation

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, access-violation

So I have a class called "TestScript" which is derived from the base class "Script". "Script" has a member called parent which is a generic pointer.
In "TestScript" I have a member of type "GameObject" called "parentObj".

So what I am trying to do is cast the generic pointer from the "Script" base class into the "parentObj" member and access one if its "GameObject" members, but this causes an Access Violation.

I have stepped though the code and confirmed the line where I access the "name" member of the "GameObject" type is where the error occurs.

Here is the code:

"Script" class definition (In "Objects.cpp"):

```
class Script
{
public:
    void* parent = NULL; // The generic pointer
    virtual void Initialize() {} // Not used
    virtual void Update() {}
    virtual void OnDestruction() {} // Also not used
};
```

"TestScript" class definition:

```
#include "Objects.cpp"

class TestScript : public Script
{
public:
    GameObject *parentObj = static_cast<GameObject*>(parent); // Casting...
    TestScript() {}
    void Update() override
    {
        std::cout << parentObj->name << std::endl; // Access violation here.
    }
};
```

The "GameObject" type is also defined in "Objects.cpp"

The generic pointer is automatically set to a "GameObject" using the **this** keyword from an already declared "GameObject" somewhere else.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Does it not surprise you that accessing a member of a null pointer results in an error?

Comment: @IllidanS4 You should read through the question more thoroughly, as at the bottom (maybe I didn't word it right) I mentioned that the pointer is set to an object of type: "GameObject".

Comment: @S.I.Spidew You should read our comments and the articles linked _more thoroughly_ please.

Comment: possibly, you set "parent" value *after* the code `GameObject *parentObj = static_cast<GameObject*>(parent);` is executed (if I'm not wrong, it's executed after base constructor and before derived class ctor)
Consider using a function: `GameObject* GetparentObj (){return static_cast<GameObject*>(parent);}`

Comment: @GianPaolo Thanks that seemed to have worked! turns out I had to delay  the `static_cast<>()` until the `parent` value was set.
Would you be able to write your comment as and answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, you set "parent" value after the code `GameObject *parentObj = static_cast<GameObject*>(parent)`; is executed (if I'm not wrong, it's executed after base constructor and before derived class ctor)

Consider using a function:

```
GameObject* GetparentObj ()
{
    return static_cast<GameObject*>(parent);
}
```